# Find a substring in a string and returning the index of the substring

Tags: python, string, indexing, substring

I have:

- a function: `def find_str(s, char)`
- and a string: `"Happy Birthday"`,

I essentially want to input `"py"` and return `3` but I keep getting `2` to return instead.

**Code:**

```
def find_str(s, char):
    index = 0           
    if char in s:
        char = char[0]
        for ch in s:
            if ch in s:
                index += 1
            if ch == char:
                return index

    else:
        return -1

print(find_str("Happy birthday", "py"))
```

Not sure what's wrong!

Comment: I'm not sure what's right with this code. You nuked your second argument with `char = char[0]`. Your second arg is just "p" after that, it finds a match at position 2 (H,a,p) and that's that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Ideally you would use [str.find](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.find) or [str.index](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.index)** like demented hedgehog said. But you said you can't ...

Your problem is your code searches only for the first character of your search string which(the first one) is at index 2.

You are basically saying if `char[0]` is in `s`, increment `index` until `ch == char[0]` which returned 3 when I tested it but it was still wrong. Here's a way to do it.

```
def find_str(s, char):
    index = 0

    if char in s:
        c = char[0]
        for ch in s:
            if ch == c:
                if s[index:index+len(char)] == char:
                    return index

            index += 1

    return -1

print(find_str("Happy birthday", "py"))
print(find_str("Happy birthday", "rth"))
print(find_str("Happy birthday", "rh"))
```

It produced the following output:

```
3
8
-1
```

Comment: I need to write an algorithm that does the .find function.  I can't just use it unfortunately!

Comment: @Tyler Edited my answer since there wasn't an actual answer to your question.

Comment: there is a better method like suggested by @demented hedgehog. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Kev1n91 I know and I said it in my answer but OP comment he couldn't use it.

Answer (score 242):

There's a builtin method [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) on string objects.

```
s = "Happy Birthday"
s2 = "py"

print(s.find(s2))
```

Python is a "batteries included language" there's code written to do most of what you want already (whatever you want).. unless this is homework :)

`find` returns -1 if the string cannot be found.

Comment: @Kev1n91 That is really strange it wasn't accepted.

Comment: I answered the question after the original answer was accepted.  I just happened upon it and thought I'd add my two cents worth.

Comment: It wasn't accepted because @Tyler couldn't use str.find or str.index

Answer (score 13):

There is one other option in [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), the `search` method

```py
import re

string = 'Happy Birthday'
pattern = 'py'
print(re.search(pattern, string).span()) ## this prints starting and end indices
print(re.search(pattern, string).span()[0]) ## this does what you wanted
```

By the way, if you would like to find all the occurrence of a pattern, instead of just the first one, you can use `finditer` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer)

```py
import re

string = 'i think that that that that student wrote there is not that right'
pattern = 'that'

print([match.start() for match in re.finditer(pattern, string)])
```

which will print all the starting positions of the matches.

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto @demented hedgehog answer on using `find()`

In terms of **efficiency**

It may be worth first checking to see if s1 is in s2 before calling `find()`.
 This can be more efficient if you know that most of the times s1 won't be a substring of s2

Since the `in` operator is very efficient

```py
 s1 in s2
```

It can be more efficient to convert:

```py
index = s2.find(s1)
```

to

```py
index = -1
if s1 in s2:
   index = s2.find(s1)
```

This is useful for when `find()` is going to be returning -1 a lot.

I found it substantially faster since `find()` was being called many times in my algorithm, so I thought it was worth mentioning

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple approach:

```
my_string = 'abcdefg'
print(text.find('def'))
```

**Output:**

**3**

I the substring is not there, you will get **-1**.
For example:

```
my_string = 'abcdefg'
print(text.find('xyz'))
```

**Output:**

**-1**

Sometimes, you might want to throw exception if substring is not there:

```
my_string = 'abcdefg'
print(text.index('xyz')) # It returns an index only if it's present
```

**Output:**

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

**File "test.py", line 6, in** 
    **print(text.index('xyz'))**

**ValueError: substring not found**

Answer (score 1):

late to the party, was searching for same, as "in" is not valid, I had just created following.

```
def find_str(full, sub):
    index = 0
    sub_index = 0
    position = -1
    for ch_i,ch_f in enumerate(full) :
        if ch_f.lower() != sub[sub_index].lower():
            position = -1
            sub_index = 0
        if ch_f.lower() == sub[sub_index].lower():
            if sub_index == 0 :
                position = ch_i

            if (len(sub) - 1) <= sub_index :
                break
            else:
                sub_index += 1

    return position

print(find_str("Happy birthday", "py"))
print(find_str("Happy birthday", "rth"))
print(find_str("Happy birthday", "rh"))
```

which produces

```
3
8
-1
```

remove lower() in case case insensitive find not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering the question but I got a similar question recently where I was asked to count the number of times a sub-string is repeated in a given string. Here is the function I wrote:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    cnt = 0
    len_ss = len(sub_string)
    for i in range(len(string) - len_ss + 1):
        if string[i:i+len_ss] == sub_string:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt
```

The find() function probably returns the index of the fist occurrence only. Storing the index in place of just counting, can give us the distinct set of indices the sub-string gets repeated within the string.

Disclaimer: I am 'extremly' new to Python programming.