# Find Part of Substring from String then Show its Substring

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string "Halo Device ANumber : 6232123123 Customer ID : 16926" 
I want to search with this keyword : "62" 
Then if there any, I want to show it's whole substring "6232123123"

```
string = str('Halo Device ANumber : 6232123123 Customer ID : 16926')
ind = string.find('62')
word = string.split()[ind]

print('62 found in index: ', ind)
print('substring : ', word)
```

output :

```
62 found in index:  22
substring : Device
```

Comment: What is `b` in your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Find a substring in a string and returning the index of the substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842885/python-find-a-substring-in-a-string-and-returning-the-index-of-the-substring)

Comment: @RoshinRaphel sorry i mean ind, i 'm just edit it thanks for correction..

Comment: @Karthik i think its not bcause i want to show whole its substring if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a particular "full string", where it ends when there is simply a space, you can just use `.find()` again:

```py
string = str('Halo Device ANumber : 6232123123 Customer ID : 16926')
target = '62'
ind = string.find(target)

ind_end = string.find(' ', ind + len(target))
word = string[ind:ind_end]
```

Now, if you wanted something more robust, we can use regex:

```py
string = str('Halo Device ANumber : 6232123123 Customer ID : 16926')
word = re.findall('(62\d+)', string).groups()[0]
```

This will take the first match from your string which starts with "62" and captures all remaining numerical digits.